# ImageButton syntax in xml

Tags: android, xml

i'm adding an imagebutton to my application 
and i'm trying to use these two ways, but neither is working:

```
<ImageButton  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and the second way:

```
<ImageButton  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageButton>
```

it gives me this error "element type imagebutton must be followed by either attribute specifications > or />

this is my xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/new_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/start_new"
                android:src="@drawable/new_pic"/>
        </LinearLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use the attribute android:background="@drawable/imagename" it will work

Comment: can u paste ur whole xml ? I guess you are missing out some layout tag or something.

Comment: There's most probably something wrong in the XML (like namespace not defined) or in your projext setup. Can you give us the full XML?

Comment: Did you ever try cleaning, because I don't see anything wrong? "Project --> Clean..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining the Component by  manual coding. try to use it via GUI. it will automatically add required attribute for any component and show you the error in the layout. Hope you have understand what I want to mean. 
 Like below: 
This is a default button if you make it by GUI

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1" // mandatory you just miss it
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/helloworld"
        android:layout_below="@+id/helloworld"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: IMHO, this is not a good suggestion. Learning how to code the `Views` manually is much easier in the long run. It seems to be more flexible and the dev gets a better feel for how the `Views` behave and what they need/can do

Comment: sure sir, But this differ from dev to dev. What I believe, As a kid- use ready-made, as a learner/pactitioner learn details of it, as  an expert use ready-made and customize it according to your necessary as you know it very well.

Comment: I agree it differs but I think its important to learn it through the xml. Also, the `id` isn't mandatory ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="@string/test_str"
    android:id="@+id/listener"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
/>
```